# show post thumbnail wordpresss not working

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code to display the thumbnail image named th-mag2 :

```
<img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail('th-mag2'); ?>" width="100%" class="object-fit card-img-top" height="150px" alt="img-news" loading="lazy">
```

But when it is displayed on the site, it is displayed as follows:

[image]

Please help me ....
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the Post Thumbnail URL only then you can not use the_post_thumbnail() function, it will print the complete Image Structure with Image tag also,

So what you actually need to do is

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('th-mag2'); ?> 

Instead of 

<img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail('th-mag2'); ?>" width="100%" class="object-fit card-img-top" height="150px" alt="img-news" loading="lazy">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but the issue looks familiar to me. So I am trying to help you.

```
<img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail('th-mag2'); ?>/images/th-mag2.jpg" width="100%" class="object-fit card-img-top" height="150px" alt="img-news" loading="lazy"/>
```

You can try this one with `.jpeg` as well instead of `.jpg` if that's your image extension.

You can also try this one if the first one doesn't work (with the correct image extension):

```
<img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>/images/th-mag2.jpg" width="100%" class="object-fit card-img-top" height="150px" alt="img-news" loading="lazy"/>
```